# addClass on click after first call doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add animation `class` to my `div` when a `link` is clicked like so :

```
var effect = "tada";
$(document).ready(
    function () {

        $("#navbar-ul a").click(function () {
            //add effect to the content
            $("#content").removeClass(effect).addClass(effect);
        });
    }
);
```

but it works first time I click on a `link` after that it doesn't , how can I fix that?

EDIT: add `effect` `variable`!

EDIT2: the effec is CSS animations, which I want to trigger by removing and adding the same class again in order to work.

Comment: Also, why remove a class to add it again?

Comment: so the `css` effect work agian!

Comment: Probably because the element does not have the class to begin with. You remove it (which does nothing) and then add it, which would add the styling changing its appearance. Any consecutive clicks will then simply remove and add it, which effectively does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing and adding the class in the same statement doesn't redraw, so it doesn't do anything, use a timeout to defer adding the class

```
var effect = "tada";
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#navbar-ul a").click(function () {
          $("#content").removeClass(effect);
          setTimeout(function() {
              $("#content").addClass(effect);
          }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I'm guessing this is for CSS animations, which you want to trigger by removing and adding the same class

Comment: @MixedCoder - if it breaks, that's unrelated, and is caused by something else.

Comment: Should be noted that the CSS animation will in most cases also animate in reverse, so removing and adding the class right away may not work the way you want, even if the animation is triggered correctly.